# the best downloader software in ubuntu?

Tags: idm

someone can tell me what is the best downloader in ubuntu? (same IDM is best) !!

Answer (score 0):

For random files from around the internet I just use the browser managers. Chrome and Firefox ones are good. For small files, that I download often and know the address of, I use `wget` command in Termial:

```
wget -c "Download_Link_here"
```

`-c` option used for continue/resumable support.